# Using VBA RegEx to find range of formats and maintain speed

Tags: regex, vba

I am using Excel to build a sophisticated Bill of Materials generated by another program. There are acceptable names for each of the items found in the BoM. However, often the item names fall outside the accepted naming convention. I would like to build a list of those poorly named items. Here is the acceptable formats. X's are numbers only. C's are indeed the letter C.

XXXXXX
X-XXXXX-XX
X-XXXXXX-XX
XX-XXXXX-XX
XX-XXXXXX-XX
X-XXXXX
X-XXXXXX
XX-XXXXX
XX-XXXXXX
X-XXXXX-XXX
XX-XXXXX-XXX
XXX-XXXXX-XXX
CCXXXXXX
CCX-XXXXX-XX
CCX-XXXXXX-XX
CCXX-XXXXX-XX
CCXX-XXXXXX-XX
CCX-XXXXX
CCX-XXXXXX
CCXX-XXXXX
CCXX-XXXXXX
CCXXX-XXXXX
CCXXX-XXXXXX
CCX-XXXXX-XXX
CCXX-XXXXX-XXX
CCXXX-XXXXX-XXX

Any other string or character in these strings would fail, ie. 24-03995-01 would be accepted, but 24-03995-D1 would not. 24-03995-01 would again be ok and so would 24-03995-01 ITEM A, 24-03995-D1 ITEM A would not.

I am not an expert at regular expression syntax, but can manage. My question is what would be the most efficient manner for any given input (a file name) to find that it does or does not match the given patterns? Are regular expressions the best approach? I am thinking I need to compare the input to all the above formats, but somehow that seems incredibly inefficient. Is there a way to narrow the reg ex syntax (again not my forte) to catch say 5 of the above pattens in a one statement and another 5 in the next, etc.? A big Select Case statement perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: And "C" is capital C?

Comment: Without being quite specific I would worry about some cases slipping through the net. I am not a regex guru but will be interested to see what the regex gurus have to say. I would probably have written quite a few separate expressions that I felt secure with and use those in a loop. What have you tried? Any code?

Comment: C is capital, yes. I have not started code yet, loops would work if I can marry up reg ex to cover a series of formats, which is what I am working on now. I suspect that if I could get away with say 3 - 5 loops for various formats then speed would be acceptable since I would drop out once I get a match.

Comment: `(?<!\S)(?:CC\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{2,3}|\d(?:-\d{2})?)?|\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{2,3}|\d(?:-\d{2})?)?|\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{3}|\d)?|\d{3})))|\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{2,3}|\d(?:-\d{2})?)?|\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{2,3}|\d(?:-\d{2})?)?|\d(?:-\d{5}-)?\d{3})))(?!\S)`

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, is it failing? Or it's just more complex than it needs to be?

Comment: A regex _trie_ is the fastest search in the world. What are the input conditions ? I.e. is each an independent string, or do you have many items in 1 string ? Do you want the ones that match the form, or ones that don't ?

Comment: First thing to do is to break down the pattern and specify it formally. There's something that's common to most of these acceptable inputs - write it down. Start with `If...Else...` then narrow it down until each branch is its definitive own alternative - then encode it in a regex.

Comment: You can't just use alternations with your forms, it's way too slow.

Comment: @sln depends how many inputs there are to process and how slow is unacceptably slow though.

Comment: VBA also doesn't support some of the features more generally found with regex. And heuristically I believe regex with Excel can be quite slow.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I think in this case, it's only about %25 slower if no trie. Either way is fast, matching a low of 190K matches/sec without trie,  to a high of 270K matches/sec with a full blown trie.

Comment: @QHarr well, there's no need for backrefs or named groups in this instance, and VBScript RegEx doesn't really care whether it's running in a ASP-Classic environment, Excel host, or VB6 application.

Comment: Here is one I am using and this works fine on the character count I have:  RegexCountMatches("6-48757-01", "\-\d{5}\-\d{2}", but i would like to expand some.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Are those the key unsupported features? I have yet to see them listed and explained anywhere for VBA. I just generally write a regex and then pull a little sad face when .Test doesn't like it in VBA.

Comment: you can try something like [`^(CC)?(\d{1,3}-)?\d{5,6}(-\d{2,3})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/W7T3Js/1)

Comment: to sln: I want to capture ones that don't match the given examples. I will pass a single string to the test routine at a time. Not a series.

Comment: Hmmm, that looks promising Slai.  Let me noodle through that one for a bit. That looks like I could have just two passes to test for match. One with CC, one without.

Comment: Slai, I am having success thus far with this pattern of reg ex. Thanks, I will post final code shortly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I'd check again, that regex matches `CC000000-00` is that one of your forms? It also matches a couple others that I don't see in the forms.

Comment: if I am counting correctly it's matching 2^7 = 128 combinations, so it's probably matching a lot more than needed.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Please don't go to any bother. If anything useful is to hand feel free to mention in VBA-RD room and tag me. I should get off my a** and have a look myself for something.

Comment: updated to match only the 26 specified cases, but seems a bit slower https://regex101.com/r/W7T3Js/2

Answer (score 2):

I've used a utility to generate a full blown regex trie (below), but you could
just put your forms into an alternation list if you want.

`(?:CC\d\d\d\d\d\d|CC\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d|CC\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d|CC\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d|CC\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d|CC\d-\d\d\d\d\d|CC\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d|CC\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d|CC\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d|CC\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d|CC\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d|CC\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d|CC\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d|CC\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d\d\d|\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d|\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d|\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d|\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d|\d-\d\d\d\d\d|\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d|\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d|\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d|\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d|\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d|\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d)`

and it's fast as well, generating about 190K matches/sec.

Below is a full blown regex trie and is faster, about 270K matches/sec.

I'm not sure about your input structure, but if checking a single string/value
at a time -

This will match NON-Compliance forms:

`^(?!(?:CC\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{2,3}|\d(?:-\d{2})?)?|\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{2,3}|\d(?:-\d{2})?)?|\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{3}|\d)?|\d{3})))|\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{2,3}|\d(?:-\d{2})?)?|\d(?:-\d{5}(?:-\d{2,3}|\d(?:-\d{2})?)?|\d(?:-\d{5}-)?\d{3})))$)[\S\s]+$`

Comment: As a matter of interest how do you test timings on this? A tool? Your own script?

Comment: @QHarr - I use a tool to develop regex. Screenshot of the bench generator http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b1.jpg

Comment: Many thanks. I had wondered. So this is your  home grown tool so to speak?

Comment: @QHarr - Hahh, in a sence. I charge $29 for it, but for you, it's free.. download it .

Comment: @QHarr -  Email support for the key, I'll send you one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173938/discussion-between-qharr-and-sln).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I ended up using.

For Each ws In Worksheets:

```
If ws.Name = "ASSEMBLY LIST" Then
ColPos = 1
Else  '------------ALL OTHER SHEETS THIS ROUTINE WILL ACCESS
ColPos = 2
End If
'--------------------------THE FOLLOWING LOOP TESTS THE NAME HANDED IN TO SEE IF MEETS ANY OF THE REGULAR EXPRESSION TEST FOR PROPERLY FORMATED NAMES
'--------------------------IF THE NAME DROPS THROUGH THE 4 TESTS THEN IT PASSED TO THE BAD NAME LISTING PAGE
If Left(ws.Name, 3) <> "BOM" And ws.Name <> "ITEM MASTER" And ws.Name <> "BAD NAMES LIST" Then
    theSheetRowCount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To theSheetRowCount
        theCount = 0
            Do While theCount < 4

                    If theCount < 4 Then

                    theResult = RegexCountMatches(ws.Cells(i, ColPos), "^(CC)?(\d{1,3}-)?\d{5,6}(-\d{2,3})?$")
                            If theResult = 1 Then
                                'Debug.Print "This Is Valid Number " & ws.Cells(i, colpos)
                                Exit Do
                            Else
                                theCount = theCount + 1
                            End If

                    theResult = RegexCountMatches(ws.Cells(i, ColPos), "^(CC)?(\d{1,3}-)?\d{5,6}(-\d{2,3})(_ITEM)(\s)(\w)?$")
                            If theResult = 1 Then
                                'Debug.Print "This Is Valid Number " & ws.Cells(i, colpos)
                                Exit Do
                            Else
                                theCount = theCount + 1
                            End If


                    theResult = RegexCountMatches(ws.Cells(i, 2), "(CC)?(\d{1,3}-)?\d{5,6}(-\d{2,3})(_ITEM)(\s)(\w)?$")
                            If theResult = 1 Then
                                'Debug.Print "This Is Valid Number " & ws.Cells(i, colpos)
                                Exit Do
                            Else
                                theCount = theCount + 1
                            End If

                    theResult = RegexCountMatches(ws.Cells(i, ColPos), "(CC)?(\d{1,3}-)?\d{5,6}(-\d{2,3})?$")
                            If theResult = 1 Then
                                'Debug.Print "This Is Valid Number " & ws.Cells(i, colpos)
                                Exit Do
                            Else
                                theCount = theCount + 1
                            End If
                End If
            Loop

                    If theCount = 4 And i <= theSheetRowCount Then
                        'Debug.Print "This Is an Invalid Number: " & ws.Cells(i, colpos) & " found on sheet " & ws.Name
                        RowCount = wsBadlist.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                            Sheets("BAD NAMES LIST").Cells(RowCount + 1, 1) = "This Is an Invalid Number:"
                            Sheets("BAD NAMES LIST").Cells(RowCount + 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, ColPos)  'ADDING NAME OF ITEM
                            Sheets("BAD NAMES LIST").Cells(RowCount + 1, 3) = ws.Cells(i, ColPos + 1)  'ADDING DESCRIPTION OF ITEM
                            Sheets("BAD NAMES LIST").Cells(RowCount + 1, 4) = "found on sheet " & ws.Name 'ADDING SHEET FOUND ON

                        theCount = 0
                    End If
    Next
End If
Next ws
```